# Downloaded and Installed on USB but it won't install

Tags: system-installation

Downloaded and Installed on USB but it won't install. It has errors, but I can't remember what it said. Can I download a fresh copy again?

Comment: In case it's not clear, you don't have to pay again to download the iso, just enter $0 as a price.

Comment: Also can you please clarify where the error occurs? During installation or after it during boot?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you certainly can download a new ISO. You can verify the download using the hash listed here: https://elementary.io/en/docs/installation#creating-an-installation-medium
The hash is listed under the section "Creating an Install Drive"

What software did you use to make the USB? I recently created a successful USB drive using Etcher. I've tried Rufus before and it also worked.